# Will Zend Studio 8.0 Javascript debugger able to debug Jquery? How?

Tags: php, jquery, zend-studio, zend-server

How can i debug a jquery.js file  using zend debuggger? Is it possible or
i can debug only pure Javascript file

If js file included in phtml file and if i am debugging the controller php file.
How can i reach the included Jquery file and debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript debugging is available in Zend Studio 8: http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio/debugging_javascript.htm

If you just need to debug a javascript file, I'd recommend using firebug. If you are debugging jQuery in particular, be sure you are using the uncompressed version: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js